# Metodo para mover picturebox numa matriz

Tags: c#

estou a criar um metodo no jogo das Damas que perimite que as peças movam, entao numa textbos insiro a posiçao da peça que qero mover e depois guarda a na variavel aux, e o utilizador na mesma textbox (textboxposicao) insere a posicao para onde quer mover a peça

Mas o metodo esta a dar me erro numa linha diz que 'A referência de objecto não foi definida como uma instância de um objecto '

Nao estou a conseguir resolver o problema alguem me pode ajudar?

Este é o metodo a linha que me da erro é a assinalada

```
private void buttonAdicionarPedra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Point peça_selecionada = new Point(-1,-1);//criamos uma variavel do tipo Point para guardar a posiçao da peça que vamos mexer
        //inicializamos-a na posiçao (-1,-1) porque estas posiçoes nao existem no tabuleiro
        char[] aux;
        Pedras pedra_aux;
        if (!this.seleçao)//se a peça nao tiver sido selecionada
        {
            aux = textBoxposicao.Text.ToCharArray(); //a variavel aux é um auxiliar para converter a textbox para vetor de carateres


            peça_selecionada = new Point(Convert.ToInt32(aux[0]), Convert.ToInt32(aux[1]));
            this.seleçao = true;//a peça foi selecionada
            buttonAdicionarPedra.Text = "Adicionar Pedra";//o botao muda de nome para AdicionarPedra
            textBoxposicao.Text = "";//coloca a textbox a branco novamente
            label1.Text = "Escolha para onde mover a peça";//muda o texto da label por cima da textbox posicao
        }
        else
        {//e a pedra foi selecionada 
           pedra_aux = play.ProcurarPedras(peça_selecionada);
            aux = textBoxposicao.Text.ToCharArray();
            pedra_aux.inserirposicao(Convert.ToInt32(aux[0]), Convert.ToInt32(aux[1]));//---------- da erro aqui 
            DesenhaPedras(play.Tabuleiro);
            buttonAdicionarPedra.Text = "Selecionar Peça";
            label1.Text = "Escolha a posição da peça que quer mover";
        }

    }
```

Este é o outro  metodo que uso neste metodo :

```
public void inserirposicao(int x, int y)//metodo criado para ajudar a guardar a posicao da peça q vamos mexer
    {
        Posiçao.X = x;
        Posiçao.Y = y;
    }
```

Comment: Veja se `play.ProcurarPedras` não está retornando `null` ou se `Pedras.Posiçao` foi inicializado ou os valor de `aux`.

Comment: Ai a questão é referente a lógica de seu programa, só com um fragmento não da para saber qual é intenção. Mas uma coisa eu percebi, o `this.seleçao` deve retornar `true` se uma peça selecionada caso ao contrário retorna `false`. Então me parece que esse `this.seleçao` está retornando `true` mesmo quando uma peça não é selecionada.

Answer (score 2):

O problema do erro é que a `peça_selecionada` é sempre `-1, -1` quando entra no `else` do `if`, porque está sempre a criar a instância no evento, deveria ser criada no escopo da classe tal como a variável `seleçao`.

Fiz aqui um exemplo onde usamos um objecto do tipo `Pedra` para substituir essa variável `seleçao` e `peça_selecionada`:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    private Pedra pedra;
    private Pedra[,] tabuleiro = new Pedra[8, 8];

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Criando algumas pedras
        tabuleiro[0, 0] = new Pedra(0, 0, "Brancas");
        tabuleiro[1, 1] = new Pedra { Posiçao = new Point(1, 1), Lado = "Brancas" };
    }

    private void buttonAdicionarPedra_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        // Fazer uma validação do input
        string input = textBoxposicao.Text;

        if (pedra is null)
        {
            Point origem = new Point(input[0] - 48, input[1] - 48);

            // Trás a 'pedra' caso exista uma pedra na posição da 'origem', senão trás 'null'
            // pedra = tabuleiro.Cast<Pedra>().FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.Posiçao == origem); // pela propriedade 'Posiçao' da pedra
            pedra = tabuleiro[origem.X, origem.Y];
        }
        else
        {
            Point destino = new Point(input[0] - 48, input[1] - 48);

            // Verifica se a posição 'destino' tem uma pedra
            // if (tabuleiro.Cast<Pedra>().FirstOrDefault(p => p != null && p.Posiçao == destino) is null) // pela propriedade 'Posiçao' da pedra          
            if (tabuleiro[destino.X, destino.Y] is null)
            {
                tabuleiro[pedra.Posiçao.X, pedra.Posiçao.Y] = null;
                // Cria uma nova instacia da 'pedra' com a nova posição 'destino' e com os outros valores da pedra
                // Não podemos atribuir a 'pedra' porque depois a iremos setar a 'null' (ficaria como 'null' tambem no 'tabuleiro')
                tabuleiro[destino.X, destino.Y] = new Pedra { Posiçao = destino, Lado = pedra.Lado };
            }
            pedra = null;
        }
        ActualizarRotulos();
    }

    private void ActualizarRotulos()
    {
        if (pedra is null)
        {
            buttonAdicionarPedra.Text = "Selecionar Peça";
            label1.Text = "Escolha a posição da peça que quer mover";
        }
        else
        {
            buttonAdicionarPedra.Text = "Adicionar Pedra";
            label1.Text = "Escolha para onde mover a peça";
        }
        textBoxposicao.Text = "";
    }
}

public class Pedra
{
    public Point Posiçao { get; set; }
    public string Lado { get; set; }
    public bool Dama = false;

    public Pedra() { }

    public Pedra(int x, int y, string lado)
    {
        this.Posiçao = new Point(x, y);
        this.Lado = lado;
    }
}
```